# Can lightGallery() be used as a callback? Can it only initialize once after page load?

Tags: jquery, callback, shopify, image-gallery, lightgallery

I'm having trouble using lightGallery() as a callback; I'm trying to use this in Shopify when a customer is selecting product options.

For example, I have a div `#lightgallery` that has 5 images, and after the page loads, `$("#lightgallery").lightGallery();` is called.

When a customer chooses a product variant, the previous 5 images in `#lightgallery` are removed, a new 4 images of the variant are created, but `$("#lightgallery").lightGallery();` doesn't initialize the new gallery for the variant.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating and destroying several lightgalleries, I found out that multiple light galleries can be instantiated at once, like so:

```
$('.gallery').lightGallery();
```

Answer (score 0):

lightGallery needs to be destroyed before a new one is instantiated. So, I call the destroy() method on the onCloseAfter event:

```
const $lg = $("#lightgallery");    
$lg.lightGallery();

$lg.one('onCloseAfter.lg',function(event){
  $lg.data('lightGallery').destroy('true');
});
```

Note `$lg.one` and NOT `$lg.on`, check out mervick's last comment here:
https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/issues/238

Answer (score 0):

Write down the below mention script on ajax success.

Note: `unitPlanslightGallery` is the `class` or `id` on which we are applying the    light gallery.

```
var lg = jQuery('.unitPlanslightGallery');
// destroy
lg.data('lightGallery').destroy(true);
```